# Fully associative cache - calculate address tag bits?

Tags: memory-management, cpu-cache, memory-access

I have the following task:

> Main memory capacity = 64MB (B = byte)
>   Cache capacity = 64KB
>   Block size = 16B
>   Processor addressed information with address A = 0052A622h
>
> Calculate address tag of associated tag and minimum/maximum address inside of that block.

This is the solution:

```
Address -     0000 0000 0101 0010 1010 0110 0010 | **0010**
Address tag - 0000 0000 0101 0010 1010 0110 0010
```

Why are we "discarding" the last 4 bits?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  1. Please ask only one question per question.  I've edited out your first question, as it isn't a good fit here (see next comment).  2. What are your thoughts?  Please edit the question to show your reasoning.  What do you think the answer should be, and why?  What reading/self-study have you done?  You might also want to take a look at http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Instead, try to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: The low 4 address bits makes 16 bytes, selecting one byte within a block.